# Check if character belongs to Set

Tags: string, scala

I have set of vowels:

```
val vowels = immutable.Set("A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "o", "u", "y")
```

And I have a set of words. And I need to check if first letter of word from set belongs to vowels.

Comment: Try with `vowels.contains(w.head)` (`w` being one of your words)

Comment: `head` should not be used - it's partial: `scala> "".head
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator`

Answer (score 3):

To check a single word:

```
scala> vowels.contains("foo".head.toString)
res2: Boolean = false

scala> vowels.contains("oops".head.toString)
res3: Boolean = true
```

To check a `List` of words:

```
scala> val words = List("foo", "bar", "ate", "elf", "baz")
words: List[String] = List(foo, bar, ate, elf, baz)

scala> words.map(w => vowels.contains(w.head.toString))
res8: List[Boolean] = List(false, false, true, true, false)
```

You can also define `vowels` as a `Char` then use `toLower` in your test:

```
scala> val vowels = Set('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
vowels: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(e, u, a, i, o)

scala> vowels.contains("Oops".head.toLower)
res18: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming word is a string:

```
     vowels(word.head)
```

will return a boolean. And depending on use case you could do something like this:

```
    words.map(vowels(_.head))
    words.filter(vowels(_.head))
```